# Repeat drawing at different angles

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, drawing, gauge

I am currently designing a sort of gauge control for a project of mine. So far all works good and the control displays just fine. How ever currently I placed all ticks of the control manually. It works but its not nice.

I was wondering if its possible easily, best in pure XAML to perform some sort of repeation. Meaning I layout one line and have WPF drawing it X-times at different angles.

Currently rendering my ticks looks like this:

```
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="18" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="36" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="54" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="72" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="108" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="126" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="144" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="162" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
    </Line.RenderTransform>
</Line>
```

While it works I do not really like it.

Any ideas how to do this better?

The remaining properties of the lines are place in a style definition by the way:

```
<Style TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource displayForeground}}" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="-85" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="-95" />
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" Value="1.00 0.00 -0.00 1.00 0 0" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I mean to add that I used a progress bar to get this component to work and altered the control template.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you expose a collection of ticks from your control, and then bind an `ItemsControl` to them. You tick object could have an `Angle` property which you can bind your `RotateTransform` to in the ItemTemplate.